# Openpyxl search in column and add if it's missing from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, openpyxl

i know it sounds quite simple but can't figure how to make it work. I have a dictionary and an excel. All i need to perform is to iterate for each key on dictionary and see if it exists on excel col2 for example. If its missing then just have to add it at the end, not in the iteration cell so it won't overwrite the existing data. So far i have reached until this point and have stuck.

```
path="some path\\test.xlsx"
my_dict={'key1':'val1','key2':'val2','key3':'val3'}

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
ws=wb.active

for i in range(2,ws.max_row+1):
    cell_data = ws.cell(row=i, column=2)
    for key in list(my_dict.keys()):
        if cell_data.value!=key:
            #print('row'+str(i)+ ' cell2'+': '+cell_obj.value)
            # print('key: '+key)
            cell_data.value = key

wb.save(path)
```

Below i have attached the input and desired output, any guidance really appreciated.

[image: data test]

[image: desired output]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a
question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: sorry, will keep in mind in future

Comment: Create a set of the values and compare it with the dictionary keys, then add the missing ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on good tracks with what you show.

This is what I propose can copy the keys of your dictionary into a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset), then iterate over your worksheet, removing the keys you find from the set, and finally iterate over the set appending to the worksheet.

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook

path = "/tmp/75043437.xlsx"

wb = load_workbook(path)
ws = wb.active

my_dict = {"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2", "key3": "val3"}

my_keys = set(my_dict.keys())

for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, values_only=True):
    try:
        my_keys.remove(row[1])
    except KeyError:
        pass

for k in my_keys:
    ws.append((None, k, None))

wb.save(path)
```

Comment: hello, if we skip set can't we iterate for each key? i mean dictionary have unique values and keys besides, trying to understand the logic behind it, thanks

Comment: The point of copying the keys in a set is to keep your original dictionary untouched, while I can remove keys from the set. If the dictionary can be destroyed, might as well use it directly.

Comment: ok now i got it. We remove keys that already exists in ws and then append only the necessary, also if its possible could you please explain the command: my_keys.remove(v[1])? i mean we remove the first key in set? anyway thanks for your patience and time, will accept your solution

Comment: `v` contains a row of the worksheet as we iterate through it. `v[1]` accesses column B. And we try to remove that from the set of keys.